# Mysql DISTINCT and COUNT query

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

im having issues getting a query to output how i want,

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.`item_id`, 
    `products`.`item_code`, 
    `products`.`item_name`, 
    `orders`.`quantity` 
FROM 
    `orders` 
    JOIN `products` ON `orders`.`item_id` = `products`.`id` 
    JOIN `suppliers` ON `products`.`supplier_ref` = `suppliers`.`supplier_ref` 
WHERE 
    `suppliers`.`id` = 159 
    AND `orders`.`order_status` = 'NOTED'
```

which is returning the results:

```
item_id item_code item_name            quantity
1271    RA001G    Green Mop Bucket 12L 2
1270    RA001     Blue Mop Bucket 12L  1
1270    RA001     Blue Mop Bucket 12L  1
```

but i would like it to bring back distinct item_id with the quantity added together how ever when i've tried to add distinct and count i end up only have one line returned.

Comment: then you should add a `group by` clause.

Comment: You want to see " 1270    RA001     Blue Mop Bucket 12L 2" for the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum up the quantities for same items, try **grouping** over item_id. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.`item_id`, 
    `products`.`item_code`, 
    `products`.`item_name`, 
    sum(`orders`.`quantity`) as quantity, 
FROM 
    `orders` 
    JOIN `products` ON `orders`.`item_id` = `products`.`id` 
    JOIN `suppliers` ON `products`.`supplier_ref` = `suppliers`.`supplier_ref` 
WHERE 
    `suppliers`.`id` = 159 
     AND `orders`.`order_status` = 'NOTED'
  GROUP BY `orders`.`item_id`, 
      `products`.`item_code`, 
      `products`.`item_name`
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much, i was grouping by item_id, but was then doing COUNT() instead of SUM() which must have been throwing it off

Answer (score 0):

Please use group by clause

```
 SELECT 
`orders`.`item_id`, 
`products`.`item_code`, 
`products`.`item_name`, 
 sum(`orders`.`quantity`) as quantity
 FROM 
  `orders` 
   JOIN `products` ON `orders`.`item_id` = `products`.`id` 
   JOIN `suppliers` ON `products`.`supplier_ref` =   `suppliers`.`supplier_ref` 
WHERE 
 `suppliers`.`id` = 159 AND `orders`.`order_status` = 'NOTED'
group by 
 `orders`.`item_id`;
```